# How to view all the steps involved in ldapsearch operation?

Tags: directory, ldap

I am using

```
$> ldapsearch -x -H ldap://<Directory Server IPv4 Address> -D cn=admin,o=myorg -s one 
-b t=TEST -v
```

to view some entries at level one in my tree, this is working fine.

Additionally I want to know/view the internal operations/messages like `Connecting to Server..` , `Binding to the Directory..` , etc. similar messages. As you can see I used `-v` option but that was not much helpful.

Is there a way to see that by enabling some option, by using some different command, or some other method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ldapsearch -d 9
od
ldapsearch -d 999

man ldapsearch 
...
 -d debuglevel
              Set the LDAP debugging level to debuglevel.  ldapsearch must  be
              compiled  with  LDAP_DEBUG  defined  for this option to have any
              effect.
...

Comment: Where were you getting the `-d` setting? I didn't see it in the Man page, and aside from guessing, I don't know where to find that information.